# SQL Query to find duplicates separated by a letter

Tags: sql, excel

I have an excel sheet of law school courses and I need to find the duplicates. How duplicates are described in this scenario is the course number with a letter at the end.

Ex course number 500 and the duplicates of that course would be 500A, 500B, 500c etc.
I need to single out all the duplicates

Comment: What have you tried? Why do you need a SQL query? Finding and eliminating duplicates is a built-in operation in Excel.

Comment: So I don’t need to eliminate them. I tried conditional formatting and then highlighting the duplicates but again the duplicates are not entered in the excel sheet as duplicates. Ex is 500, 500A. But I need them pulled from the excel sheet not just highlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion of resolution:
If you have the data
`INSERT INTO "main"."courses" ("id", "name") VALUES ('1', '500'),('2', '400'),('3', '500A'),('4', '500B'),('5', '300');`
You can execute the following request:

```
with cte as (select id, name, case when length(name)> 3 then SUBSTR(name, 1,LENGTH(name)-1) else name end as root
from courses )
select *
from courses a
inner join cte b on b.root = a.name
where a.name != b.name
```

It's just an exemple. Depending on your database management system, there are different ways to truncate the last character of the course number.